# how to add 50% random normal noise to Mnist dataset in python

Tags: python, noise, deterministic

I'm trying to make the MNIST dataset noisy based on an article where noises were added by percentage. I don't know how to calculate the percentage of noise added to an image.

Here is my Python code:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255
noise_factor = 0.5
x_train_noisy = X_train + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=X_train.shape) 
x_test_noisy = X_test + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=X_test.shape) 
x_train_noisy = np.clip(x_train_noisy, 0., 1.)
x_test_noisy = np.clip(x_test_noisy, 0., 1.)
```

1.Is the percentage of this noise 50% (based on noise_factor)? Can noise factor show us the percentage?

2.Are there other ways to add noise with percentage?

3.Are deterministic distribution and non-random same things? I saw an article where they added noise with percentage and based on deterministic distribution but looked for it and got nothing.

Comment: Usually, noise is not added as percentage. instead you can specify the variance of your normal distribution in order to choose the noise amount. you can try with a value of .1 for starters.

Comment: Actually i know this.But I have to add it by percentage.Because I'm simulating an article and they used percentage and our results should be just like that article.

Comment: please see my answer and if you have further questions comment below that

Comment: could you please give me a link?

Comment: my answer to your question, which is in this page itself. refresh your page if you dont see it

Answer (score 1):

1. The noise is not in terms of percentage. Generally , you draw noise from a standard normal distribution and you multiply it with a factor (in your case, it is .5)
2. Whenever dealing with percentages, you need to specify percentage with respect to *what*. If you have that , then you can draw randomly from there (however i have not seen it in practice).
3. Provide more info , but if something is deterministic, it means it is non random. It is possible to make your random model deterministic by specifying a seed value, but this is usually to produce exact same random values between experiments.

Comment: So how do people usually specify it?Can you name some?

Comment: they draw from a normal distribution. the amount is varied by selecting the variance of the distribution (or they just draw from standard normal distribution and multiply it by a factor)

Comment: and by the way, this is that article that i'm talking about.they use percentage but they didn't mension how to calculate it.https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8079976

Comment: I would say its simply the strength of the gaussian. so you can multiply the standard normal by .5 (like you have)

Comment: @mahyarsadeghi You have an answer in your other question explaining what they probably did to add the noise. You didn't ask for clarifications so I assume you understood the answer. Why are you asking the same again?